# Multiple INSERT INTO statements dropping data

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to insert stock data from multiple company stock tables into one portfolio table. I have 4 insert into statements, and they all run without error, but only the data from the first statement is actually inserted.

I also need to insert the associated date with each stock entry. Each company's table has it's own date column. How do I insert the date that each stock entry is associated with, assuming that some stocks have an earlier start date than others(and thus some stock's entries will be null for a certain date) and also join one or more entries that have the same date.

I've commented out the first insert statement, which results in the second statements data showing up, but again, no data from the subsequent statements.

```
INSERT INTO portfolio (date, GOOG_adjusted_close) 
SELECT date, GOOG.close
FROM GOOG
ORDER BY date ASC;

INSERT INTO portfolio (date, CELG_adjusted_close) 
SELECT date, CELG.close
FROM CELG
ORDER BY date ASC;

INSERT INTO portfolio (date, NVDA_adjusted_close) 
SELECT date, NVDA.close
FROM NVDA
ORDER BY date ASC;

INSERT INTO portfolio (date, FB_adjusted_close) 
SELECT date, FB.close
FROM FB
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

I've also tried combining them into one statement, but it it results in the code taking way longer than I think it should(each company table has about 251 rows, as should the portfolio table), so I kill it. I also here run into the issue of each company table having it's own date column and I need to join them.

```
INSERT INTO portfolio (date, GOOG_adjusted_close, CELG_adjusted_close, NVDA_adjusted_close, FB_adjusted_close) 
SELECT GOOG.date, GOOG.close, CELG.close, NVDA.close, FB.close
FROM GOOG, CELG, NVDA, FB
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

I should get data for each stock's closing price for a given date(assuming the data exists for that date. However, only the date and closing price from the first INSERT INTO works, the rest show up as null.

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjc6R.png)

[Example of the CSV files, they are loaded into a table for the respective company, and from those tables into the portfolio table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5zHw.png)

Comment: MySql <> SQL Server

Comment: @ZoharPeled sorry, I'm a bit new to stackoverflow, what do you mean by "MySql <> SQL Server"?

Comment: he is asking witch database system you are using.

Comment: Your Problem is that you have to join your tables by a criteria. Buid at first a SeLCT with all your tables that have the wanted result.

Comment: How do you run these insert statements? separately or all together? If you run them all toghether some IDEs runs only the first one in some cases. So try to run them separately.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I'm using mySQL 5.7, sorry I thought one was a subset of the other. The statements are run in order alltogether, basically the way I have them in my original post is how they are in the query file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a slightly different approach where data in portfolio is defined as a primary or unique key and the inserts have an on duplicate key clause (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). For example

```
drop table if exists goog,celg,portfolio;
create table portfolio(date date primary key,goog_adjusted_close int,CELG_adjusted_close int);
create table goog(date date ,close int);
create table celg(date date ,close int);
insert into goog values
('2010-01-01',1),('2010-02-01',2);
insert into celg values
('2010-01-01',1),('2010-02-01',2),('2010-03-01',3);

truncate table portfolio;
INSERT INTO portfolio (date, GOOG_adjusted_close) 
SELECT date, GOOG.close
FROM GOOG
on duplicate key update goog_adjusted_close = goog.close;

INSERT INTO portfolio (date, CELG_adjusted_close) 
SELECT date, CELG.close
FROM CELG
on duplicate key update celg_adjusted_close = celg.close;

select * from portfolio; 

+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| date       | goog_adjusted_close | CELG_adjusted_close |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2010-01-01 |                   1 |                   1 |
| 2010-02-01 |                   2 |                   2 |
| 2010-03-01 |                NULL |                   3 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You may be able to drop the order by in the inserts since it serves not purpose.

Comment: Thanks! This achieved what I was looking for, I had misunderstood the insert into command, and my "dropped data" was actually showing up at the bottom, as each insert added more rows.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this what you want:

```
INSERT INTO portfolio (date, GOOG_adjusted_close, CELG_adjusted_close, NVDA_adjusted_close, FB_adjusted_close)     
    SELECT date,
           MAX(GOOG_adjusted_close),
           MAX(CELG_adjusted_close),
           MAX(NVDA_adjusted_close),
           MAX(FB_adjusted_close)
    FROM ((SELECT date, GOOG.close as GOOG_adjusted_close, NULL as CELG_adjusted_close, NULL as NVDA_adjusted_close, NULL as FB_adjusted_close
           FROM GOOG
           ) UNION ALL
           (SELECT date, NULL, CELG.close, NULL, NULL
            FROM CELG
           ) UNION ALL
           (SELECT date, NULL, NULL, NVDA.close, NULL
            FROM NVDA
           ) UNION ALL
           (SELECT date, NULL, NULL, NULL, FB.close
            FROM FB
           )
          ) d
    GROUP BY date;
```

This combines all the data onto a single row.  Your version puts all the values in the Google column -- which is probably not what you want.

If you use `JOIN`, you need to be careful, in case the dates do not precisely overlap among the different tables.

Comment: This gives me the error "Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"; I probably should have mentioned earlier that for each adjusted close column, there's an additional two columns after for calculated values. Given that, and assuming I'm reading the code right, I should add more NULL values in between, to match the columns of the table exactly?

Comment: @NeziricM . . . All the columns should be in the list for the `INSERT()`.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought that if I named the destination column in the portfolio table, that the query would insert the source column into, rather than just go in order.

Comment: @NeziricM . . . SQL doesn't work like that.  The columns are named in the `INSERT` and the values are assigned based on column position.

Comment: Is there a better way to insert data form multiple tables if one has many columns? Essentially is there a way to avoid writing many NULLs.

Comment: Looking back to when I comment out the insert for GOOG, the insert for CELG is inserted into the correct column, Wouldn't that suggest that as long as I name the destination column, it'll insert into the right column?

Comment: @NeziricM . . . Yes.  It is the column list in the `INSERT` that determines the destination columns.